# Can't Get Response From Ajax Call If Json Response Includes Slash

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I'm developing `jquery mobile` app and trying to make `ajax` call on my localhost, when i try to get `json` value with `ajax`, it gives these errors `jQuery.ajaxTransport.send` `jQuery.extend.ajax` ..

I'm really confused about this situation and i couldn't find any solution. If i remove or replace the slashes before `ajax` gets the `json` value from my script, it works fine, but i have lots of url value in my `json` and dont want to replace all of them. I have to learn why is it happening. Hope you can help me.

**Json Value**

```
[{"Video_URL":"http:\/\/localhost\/video-1-season-trailer\/","Subtitle_URL":"http:\/\/localhost\/wp-content\/uploads\/abc.srt","Video_Image":"http:\/\/localhost\/wp-content\/uploads\/small-icons\/aaa.jpg","post_title":"Video Season 1","post_id":13649,"post_view":"2359","engsub":"none"}]
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost/androidjsonvol/?kategorisezon='+get_Cat+'&sezon=true&callback=?',
    dataType: "json", // or jsonp
    success: function(cat_Response){
       var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(cat_Response);
       $.mobile.changePage('bolum.html', { data : myJsonString, reloadPage : true, changeHash : true });

        }, error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
         //error log
        }
  });
```

**php side**

```
$series_infos[]= array(
 'Video_URL'=>$video_url, /* e.g http://localhost/video-1-season-trailer/ */
 'Subtitle_URL'=>$video_sub,
 'Video_Image'=>$small_icon,
 'post_title'=>$post_title,
 'post_id'=>$post_id,
 'post_view'=>$view_count,
 'engsub'=>$engsub 
);

//for json 
 echo json_encode($series_infos);
// for jsonp
//echo $_GET['callback']. '(' . json_encode($series_infos) . ');';

/* ajax cant get this encoded value because it includes slash
 but somehow if i change the array values with any string 
 without slash e.g : "stringvaluesforarray" it works fine */
```

Comment: What's the actual response body?

Comment: Sorry, did you mean error responseText ?

Comment: If the "Json Value" you've mentioned is the actual response body, your code shouldn't have any issues with it.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this solution :

**Ajax :**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", // Depending on your type
    url: "your_file.php", // Your php file
    dataType: 'json', // Use jsonp to call cross-domain
    success: function(response) {
        // Using for each
        $.each(response, function(index, element) {
            // Do something with every element
            $('body').append(element);
        });
    }
});
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php

    // For example you have array of Urls
    $array = array('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.twitter.com', 'http://www.twitter.com');

    // Then storing the Json Encode in a variable
    $json = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

    // Remove Backslashes from that variable
    $parse = preg_replace('/\\\"/',"\"", $json);

    // Return the Urls after removing backslashes
    echo $parse;

?>
```

it's returning :

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.youtube.com
http://www.twitter.com
```

Hope that helps.

**Edit :**

if you want to use ajax cross-domain you can use **jsonp** in your ajax type.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i tried your code but it did not solve my problem completely. But finally i found the solution. It is about the cross domain. I was working on `PHP Storm` and my jquery mobile project local url was : `http://localhost:63342/` and the ajax target was `http://localhost/some.php`

Comment: The only way to use Ajax Cross-Domain is to use JsonP dataType in your ajax. glad that you found a solution.